# Wildchars in tags preferences

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching, ignored-tags, wildcards

There are favorite and ignored tags in Preferences. They need to explicitly list your tags. I would like to have wild char support here, so for example `*PHP*` will find `PHP`, `PHP3`, `PHP4`, `PHPUnit`, `CakePHP` and all other PHP tags.

Comment: Did you try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php*) or [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/*php*)?

Comment: Adding `*php*` as a favourite seems to work.

Comment: I tried to add php*, but asterisk was silently removed. It looked to me, that I have to SELECT tag from offerred options.

Comment: @devnull This is something else.

Comment: to down-voter: Why? This feature did not work to me, because keyboard is not supported correctly. When I wrote this question, I browsed offered questions and this question was not there. So blame SO related search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is [already supported](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/interesting-and-ignored-tags-now-support-wildcards/). Have you tried it? Just edit your favorite tags and add a tag with wildcard e.g. enter `php*` (as you said):

> [image]

This works fine.

Comment: I tried to add this tag with keyboard (enter key) and it saved PHP only. Now I tried to CLICK button ADD and it saved my filter.